# Email and Password form in one row with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I started bootstrap very recently. I want to create email/ password validation in one row on my rails app:

`email? | password? | OK`

Right now, I have a code working for just an email and OK button in one row:

`email? | OK`

```
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center">
...
  <form class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="center-block form-control input-lg" title="Enter your email." placeholder="email?">
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">OK</button></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and

```
.v-center {
  margin-top:7%;
}
```

I tried adding a password on the code above:

```
...
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="center-block form-control input-lg" title="Enter your email." placeholder="email">
      <input type="text" class="center-block form-control input-lg" title="Enter your password." placeholder="password">
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">OK</button></span>
...
```

But it ended up looking like this:

```
email?
          | OK
password?
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bootstrap's `.center-block` has `display: block;` in it. If you want elements to appear side-by-side, they generally need a `display` of `inline` or `inline-block` in the css (there are a few other ways, but both those are arguably the most common/simplest).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for this: The trick is to use "form-inline" class in the form tag

```
   <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```